# Qt: QFuture/QtConcurrent timeout function call

Tags: c++, qt

I need a timeout function call. I work mainly with Qt (4.7.3, 4.8.5) and so i tried to find a solution with Qt. The two classes QFuture and QtConcurrent seems to do 99% of what i need but i can not find a possibility to timeout a function call.

**My Problem:**
I have my tester (gtest) and i test a function which can end in an infinity loop => so i want to test this to fix that problem[s] (this function is internal extrem complex :-( ). I want to add a timeout-time to break out if there is an infinity loop => so i can tell the tester that something is wrong (infinity loop) and i will terminate the thread.

I have search for something like that:

```
QtConcurrent::run(............,30000 /*30 seconds timeout)*/;
```

**Does anybody know how i can do this?**
(If it is possible with native C++, or boost, or ... you can also tell me your solution)

Comment: Do you need to use `QtConcurrent`? Otherwise I would just create a `QThread` subclass that calls the function in its `run` method, and use `wait` with the timeout. You can even `terminate` the thread if it is stuck, but use this with caution! (see docs)

Comment: @Laszlo Did you find something like QtConcurrent::run(............,30000 /*30 seconds timeout)*/;

Was looking for the same.

Comment: @Dhanesh: you are asking the wrong person. :)

Comment: Oops... wanted to ask this to tonka... 
:(

Answer (score 2):

I was focusing on the QtConcurrent module, since you mentioned it in your question. But you can achieve your goal also with plain QThread:

```
// A Thread calling your test function
class MyThread : public QThread {
protected:
  void run() { myFunction(); }
};


// calling the function
MyThread t;
t.start();
if ( t.wait(30000) ) {
  // Finished
} else {
  // Not finished
  // ATTENTION: USE TERMINATE WITH CARE (see QThread documentation)!
  t.terminate();
}
```

The call to terminate will forceably stop the thread and thus stop the execution of your function. Note however that the thread cannot cleanup, and any resources used by your function are not freed properly.

---

**Old Answer:**
You can do this with Qt, using a `QFutureWatcher`, a `QTimer`, and a helper `QEventLoop` . Setup your concurrent run, and watch the result with the watcher. Set the Timout with the timer, and wait until either is finished, in a Event loop.

```
// Setup eventloop, watcher and timer
QEventLoop loop;
QFutureWatcher watcher;
QObject::connect( &watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
QTimer::singleShot( 30000, &loop, SLOT(quit()) );

// Start function call
QFuture<T> future = QtConcurrent::run(...);

// Watch the call
watcher.setFuture( future );

// Wait until event loop finishes
loop.exec();

// Now either future has finished, or timeout was reached...
if ( future.isFinished() ) {
  // Function completed!
} else {
  future.cancel();
  // Infinite loop...
}
```

Comment: It won't work. From Qt docs: "Be aware that not all asynchronous computations can be canceled. For example, the future returned by QtConcurrent::run() cannot be canceled"

Comment: @IvanGrynko Ok, it cannot be canceled, I overlooked that comment. But the process will continue when the function is stuck in an infinite loop, and the caller can find out this fact. But with this restriction, I would **not recommend to use this in production code, only for testing purposes**

Comment: Thank you king_nak. That was excatly what is was looking for.

The code works but i read in the qt-documentation that it is not possible to cancel Qt::Concurrent::run call's :-( 
So when i call future.cancel it will not really cancel the "process" => that will not solve my problem :-(

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot safely terminate a thread without thread's cooperation. The thread may be accessing some shared data structure, like the C-runtime heap, and if it is terminated forcefully then such data structures will remain in a mid-change state, essentially corrupted. Any future access to them from within the program will likely cause a crash or worse.

The case of an infinite loop is not by any means different from other bad scenarios. What if the function you launch crashes the program, how do you report it to the tester?

In your case you simply don't trust the code that you're executing. The solution is to launch it in a separate *process*, whose safe termination is guaranteed by the operating system. By isolating the tested code from the tester application you guarantee that you can detect all kind of problems, including timeouts or abnormal termination.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to find out why the infinite loop happens rather than trying to fix symptoms.

`QtConcurrent::run()` uses thread pool to run tasks. You can't safely terminate thread, so the only way to safely finish a task is to `return` from it.

If you still want timeouts, you can add something like this to your function with loop:

```
QTime t;
t.start();

// it's your loop
while( true ) {

    if( t.elapsed() > 30*1000 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: > I think you need to find out why the infinite loop happens rather than trying to fix symptoms.
Absolutly, but my problem is that the unit-test on the server freeze an so all processes are freezed in the test-suite :-(

Answer (score -2):

You can bind a QTimer signal to the slot:

```
auto process = QtConcurrent::run(...);
QTimer& timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=, &process]() {
  process.cancel();
});
timer->start(3000);
```

Edit: As the cancel() method won't work on the QtConcurrent::run function, the easiest thing would be to use some kind of isRunning flag:

```
bool isRunning = true;
void runnable() {
  while (isRunning) {
    ...
  }
}

auto process = QtConcurrent::run(runnable);
QTimer& timer = new QTimer();
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=, &isRunning]() {
  isRunning = false;
});
timer->start(3000);
```

Comment: It won't work. From Qt docs: "Be aware that not all asynchronous computations can be canceled. For example, the future returned by QtConcurrent::run() cannot be canceled"

Comment: Yeah, actually the cancel() method won't work, but the idea is to set cancel flag, so the running thread will know when to stop. And this can be easily done using QTimer.

Comment: Your second code snippet has a data race. Access to `isRunning` is unsynchronized.