# Qt: How to execute a function with timeout

Tags: multithreading, qt

In Qt, what is the easiest way to execute a function with a particular timeout.(preferably in a different thread)

If the function is not returned within a specific time, error should be returned.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903139/qt-qfuture-qtconcurrent-timeout-function-call/

Comment: Yeah it is.. 
Was looking for a native solition in Qt like a concurrent::run() with a timeout option.
Looks like it is not available.

Comment: Does the function have side-effects? Then it will need to "cooperate" to be safe, i.e. check regularly whether it should quit or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a one-shot timer with [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) and when it triggers, send a signal to a receiving object on the other thread by connecting the timeout() signal to the other thread object's slot.

Then, connect the same timer's timeout to a slot in the current thread to start a timeout error timer. If the other thread returns, stop the error timer.

Answer (score 0):

The static method `QTimer::singleShot` can do it without creating a `QTimer`:

```
void MyClass::start() {
    int timeout = 500; // msecs
    QTimer::singleShot( timeout, this, SLOT(mySlot());
}

void MyClass::mySlot() {
    /* Start your thread or whatever */
}
```