# How can I exit a function after X period of time? C++

Tags: c++

I'm not really that good in C++, actually I'm new at this and still I have to much to learn.

I have this situation where a function its called and sometimes It takes thousands of seconds to complete and returns nothing.

Is there a way to put a timeout to exit that function once after I hit a time, let's say... 5 seconds

EDIT:
*I'm using qt also

Comment: No, there is not a way to do this. Perhaps you have an infinite loop? Could you include the function that is causing the issue?

Comment: I can include it due to copyright stuff, but that function basically writes into a log file. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to determine where in the function it takes so long?

Comment: Unless you can edit the function itself to check a clock or a flag and exit, the only 100% safe way to do this is run the function in a different process and kill the process. Don't try to do this with threads because killing a tardy thread can fail you in many unpredictable ways. Too damn much work, in most cases, so try to resolve the problem inside the function.

Comment: We found that sometimes takes so long because the server we are using its having trouble and the writes  to the logs keep going and stay there forever. Its code from de 90's so a lot of stuff its bad-coded, it's very frustrating

Comment: You want a `std::future<T>::wait_for`.

Comment: Normally I get cranky when people say stuff like "It came from the <long past era> so it's bad code." but in the case of C++, people were still figuring out what was and wasn't good C++ code back in the 90s. I know for a fact that the C++ I did in the 90s might as well have been C. Probably would have been better if it was pure C.

Comment: Maybe QTimer is what you are looking for?
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140643/qt-how-to-execute-a-function-with-timeout)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to modify the function, it's fairly straightforward; just have the function declare a [QElapsedTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qelapsedtimer.html) object and periodically check it to see if "too much" time has passed:

```
void MyFunctionThatShouldntTakeMoreThanFiveSeconds()
{
   QElapsedTimer timer;
   timer.start();

   while(1)
   {
      if (timer.hasExpired(5000))
      {
         printf("Time's up!  Returning now\n");
         return;
      }

      // do other stuff that the function does
   }
}
```

If you can't modify the function, OTOH, you're out of luck -- there's very little you can do to affect its behavior unilaterally.  (As @user4581301 suggests, you could spawn a child process and run the function inside the child process, and then kill the child process after 5 seconds, but that's probably more overhead and complexity than is reasonable)

Comment: Well I think I can modify that function but I have to ask if they allow me to do that, thanks.